# Pyspark add header to detail and write o/p

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am declaring a variable which has the column names. I need to add the values from a combination of variables and constant strings and write to an o/p file.

I tried the below code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Define column names
log_column_names = ["EXE_SRCE_TYP_CD","EXE_TGT_TYP_CD","EXE_ACT_TYP_CD","EXE_DT","EXE_TS","EXE_STAT_TYP_CD","EXE_SRCE_VALUE","ERR_DESC_TXT","FOLDER_NAME"]

schema = StructType([StructField(col, StringType(), True) for col in log_column_names])

log_data = [("FILEA", "FILEB", "Date Validation between FILEA and FILEB", current_date(), current_timestamp(), "Success", processing_date, ctlfile_data_as_of_date, "Value matched between FILEA and FILEB.", folder_name)]

log_data_df = spark.createDataFrame(log_data, schema = schema)

log_data_df.write.partitionBy("DOMAIN_NAME", "DATA_AS_OF_DATE").mode("append").parquet(py_log_file_path)
        dbutils.notebook.exit(datefile_data_as_of_date)
```

`processing_date` and `folder_name` are variables that are set in the code.

But it's throwing this error:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to materialize all the data that you are puting in dataframe eg. `folder_name` and `ctlfile_data_as_of_date`, etc. before you create a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If I use your code as it is just replacing variables such as current_date() and current_time() with normal string variables, everything works fine which indicates that the problem is with these two variables. See below code:

```
log_column_names = ["EXE_SRCE_TYP_CD","EXE_TGT_TYP_CD","EXE_ACT_TYP_CD","EXE_DT","EXE_TS","ok","EXE_STAT_TYP_CD","EXE_SRCE_VALUE","ERR_DESC_TXT","FOLDER_NAME"]

schema = StructType([StructField(col, StringType(), True) for col in log_column_names])

log_data = [("FILEA", "FILEB", "Date Validation between FILEA and FILEB", "ok", "kk", "Success", processing_date, ctlfile_data_as_of_date, "Value matched between FILEA and FILEB.", folder_name)]

log_data_df = spark.createDataFrame(log_data, schema = schema)
```

I tried another version using python's datetime module to fetch todays date and current time and that works just fine.:

```
from datetime import *
processing_date="2022-02-15"
ctlfile_data_as_of_date="2022-02-12"
folder_name="anything"
log_column_names = ["EXE_SRCE_TYP_CD","EXE_TGT_TYP_CD","EXE_ACT_TYP_CD","EXE_DT","EXE_TS","EXE_STAT_TYP_CD","ok","EXE_SRCE_VALUE","ERR_DESC_TXT","FOLDER_NAME"]
print(len(log_column_names))
log_data = [("FILEA", "FILEB", "Date Validation between FILEA and FILEB", str(datetime.today().date()), str(datetime.now()), "Success", processing_date, ctlfile_data_as_of_date, "Value matched between FILEA and FILEB.", folder_name)]

log_data_df = spark.createDataFrame(log_data, schema = log_column_names)
log_data_df.show()
```

Important : Lines of code that you shared have one column short. The data has 10 columns and your list of columns has a length of 9 so I added a column named "ok" to fit data.